# bash command to create single ssh grep command using multiple values from a text file

Tags: bash, grep

Im using a bash shell under RHEL6, 
I have a text file with three entries..

```
{text file}
lel
jts
sld
```

looking to find the shortest script/single line command to generate a single ssh command to reduce the number of times I am accessing a machine

```
{end result}
ssh id@machine "grep -e lel -e jts -e sld {filename}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

txtFile1="$1"
txtFile2="$2"

grepCmd="grep"

for i in $(cat $txtFile1); do
  grepCmd="$grepCmd -e $i"
done

ssh id@machine "$grepCmd $txtFile2"
```

Execute like:

```
./script "text file" "filename"
```

Comment: this doesn't get me onto a remote machine and executing the grep using all three of the values in the file on my local box

Comment: Ahh apologies, I'll add that

Comment: Does it work for you now... Or do you have to provide ssh password too?

Comment: Copying an ssh public key makes these scripts a tad easier to write

Comment: --I already have keys so good to go there.

--I am trying to avoid SSHing for each entry in the text file..  I would like to ssh once and grep using all values at once but cant seem to pass the grep -e {value} -e {value} -e {value}

Comment: Above solution should work I guess then, unless I'm misinterpreting something

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh id@machine egrep '\|lel\|jts\|sld' {filename}
```

the arguments for ssh commandline has to be escaped, because the get expanded two times

```
ssh id@machine egrep "$(readarray -t t<file1; printf "%s" "${t[0]}"; printf -- "\|%s" "${t[@]:1}")" file2
```

where file1 is your {text file} and file2 is the other {filename} on the remote machine

Answer (score 0):

If the remote machine has Gnu grep (and maybe even if it has some other grep), you can use `-f -` to read regex patterns one at a time from stdin:

```
ssh id@machine grep -f - {filename} < {patterns.txt}
```

(Note that `< {patterns.txt}` is a redirect on your machine for the `ssh` command. Don't quote it to pass it as part of the command.)

Constructing commands for remote execution by `ssh` is always a bit fragile because `ssh` actually passes the command (or the command arguments concatenated with a single space character between each one) as a single string to the user's shell on the remote machine, using the `-c` option. This means that you need to think hard about how to quote arguments, in case that might be necessary. That's especially annoying when the arguments being passed are coming from somewhere else, as in your case: if the lines of the file contain whitespace or shell metacharacters, then you would need to arrange for the lines to be escaped appropriately so that the remote shell will interpret them correctly.

Bash's built-in `printf` utility contains the `%q` format code, which is extremely useful for constructing such command lines. For example, the following should safely quote patterns contained in a file:

```
ssh id@machine "grep $(
  while IFS= read -r; do
    printf -- "-e %q " "$REPLY"
  done < {patterns.txt}) {filename}"
```

Alternatively, as a possibly more readable two-liner:

```
mapfile -t patterns < {patterns.txt}
ssh id@machine "grep $(printf -- "-e %q " "${patterns[@]}") {filename}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you some flexibility you could use the following **awk** solution, just generating the command and printing it:

```
$ awk -v n="id@machine" -v f="filename" '\
{a=((a)?a:"") " -e" $1}END{printf "ssh %s \"grep %s %s\"\n", n, a, f}' text
ssh id@machine "grep  -elel -ejts -esld filename"
```

If you, however, are interested in actually **executing** your ssh, and grabbing the output, you'll need something like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{a=((a)?a:"") " -e" $1}                    # build up list of "-e ..."
END{
   cmd="ssh " n " \"grep " a  " " f "\""   # concatenate cmd with vars "n" and "f"
   r=((cmd|getline line) > 0 ?line:"")     # execute cmd. check for errors.
   print r                                 # print result r
   close(cmd)                              # close the cmd
}
```

which you can call like:

```
awk -v n="id@machine" -v f="filename" -f tst.awk text
```

or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk -v n="id@machine" -v f="filename" '{a=((a)?a:"") " -e" $1}END{cmd="ssh " n " \"grep " a  " " f "\"";r=((cmd|getline line) > 0 ?line:"");print r;close(cmd)}' text
```

You could use this in a bash script, looping over several machines and files. The only thing you need to do is to replace the `n` and `f` variables with your resp. bash vars.